Discord.Py Cogs And Slash Command
I'm trying to make a bot with moderation cog file. Firstly I added ban and unban but it is not working.
my files look like. I think files are in correct positions.

Main command:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

from .cogs import ban

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True  # Required for on_member_join listener

client = commands.Bot(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Move Move Move")

def setup(bot):
    ban(bot)

setup(client)

client.run("token")

ban cog:
import discord
from discord import interactions
from discord.ext import commands


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=discord.Intents.all())

class ban(commands.Cog):

  def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot
  @client.tree.command(name="ban", description="Bans a member from the server.")
  @commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
  async def ban(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, reason=None):
    """Bans a member from the server.

    Args:
        ctx (discord.ext.commands.Context): The command context.
        member (discord.Member): The member to ban.
        reason (str, optional): The reason for banning the member. Defaults to None.
    """
    if member == ctx.author:
      await ctx.respond("You can't ban yourself!")
      return

    if member == ctx.guild.owner:
      await ctx.respond("I can't ban the server owner!")
      return

    if member.top_role >= ctx.author.top_role:
      await ctx.respond("You can't ban someone with a higher role than you!")
      return

    try:
      await member.ban(reason=reason)
      await ctx.respond(f"{member} has been banned!")
    except discord.HTTPException as e:
      await ctx.respond(f"Failed to ban {member}. Error: {e}")

  @client.tree.command(name="unban", description="Unbans a member from the server.")
  @commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)  # Requires "Ban Members" permission
  async def unban(self, ctx, user: discord.User, *, reason=None):
    """Unbans a member from the server.

    Args:
        ctx (discord.ext.commands.Context): The command context.
        user (discord.User): The user to unban (use their ID).
        reason (str, optional): The reason for unbanning the member. Defaults to None.
    """
    try:
      guild = ctx.guild
      banned_users = await guild.bans()
      member = [ban for ban in banned_users if ban.user == user]

      if not member:
        await ctx.respond(f"{user} is not banned from this server.")
        return

      await guild.unban(user, reason=reason)
      await ctx.respond(f"{user} has been unbanned!")
    except discord.HTTPException as e:
      await ctx.respond(f"Failed to unban {user}. Error: {e}")

def setup(bot):
  bot.add_cog(ban(bot))


error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\playe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\cogs\ban.py", line 8, in <module>
    class ban(commands.Cog):
  File "C:\Users\playe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\cogs\ban.py", line 12, in ban
    @client.tree.command(name="ban", description="Bans a member from the server.")
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\playe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 887, in decorator
    command = Command(
              ^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\playe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 666, in __init__
    self._params: Dict[str, CommandParameter] = _extract_parameters_from_callback(callback, callback.__globals__)
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\playe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 371, in _extract_parameters_from_callback
    raise TypeError(f'parameter {parameter.name!r} is missing a type annotation in callback {func.__qualname__!r}')
TypeError: parameter 'reason' is missing a type annotation in callback 'ban.ban'

Process finished with exit code 1

I changed commands.slash_command with client.tree.command.

You must load your cogs in an asynchronous context.
In ban cog file:
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands

class BanCog(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot

  @app_commands.command(name="ban", description="Bans a member from the server.")
  @commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
  async def ban(self, ctx: commands.Context, member: discord.Member, reason=None):
    """Bans a member from the server.

    Args:
        ctx (discord.ext.commands.Context): The command context.
        member (discord.Member): The member to ban.
        reason (str, optional): The reason for banning the member. Defaults to None.
    """
    if member == ctx.author:
      await ctx.respond("You can't ban yourself!")
      return

    if member == ctx.guild.owner:
      await ctx.respond("I can't ban the server owner!")
      return

    if member.top_role >= ctx.author.top_role:
      await ctx.respond("You can't ban someone with a higher role than you!")
      return

    try:
      await member.ban(reason=reason)
      await ctx.respond(f"{member} has been banned!")
    except discord.HTTPException as e:
      await ctx.respond(f"Failed to ban {member}. Error: {e}")

  @app_commands.command(name="unban", description="Unbans a member from the server.")
  @commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)  # Requires "Ban Members" permission
  async def unban(self, ctx: commands.Context, user: discord.User, *, reason=None):
    """Unbans a member from the server.

    Args:
        ctx (discord.ext.commands.Context): The command context.
        user (discord.User): The user to unban (use their ID).
        reason (str, optional): The reason for unbanning the member. Defaults to None.
    """
    try:
      guild = ctx.guild
      banned_users = await guild.bans()
      member = [ban for ban in banned_users if ban.user == user]

      if not member:
        await ctx.respond(f"{user} is not banned from this server.")
        return

      await guild.unban(user, reason=reason)
      await ctx.respond(f"{user} has been unbanned!")
    except discord.HTTPException as e:
      await ctx.respond(f"Failed to unban {user}. Error: {e}")

async def setup(bot):
  await bot.add_cog(BanCog(bot))

In main file:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True  # Required for on_member_join listener
bot = commands.Bot(intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Move Move Move")

async def main():
  async with bot:
    await bot.load_extension("cogs.ban")
    await bot.start("TOKEN")

asyncio.run(main())

